# DXA 2.2 - Dynamic Navigation - The way to associate keyword metadata

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.1

I am trying to use the intelligent (Dynamic) navigation based on taxonomy in DXA 2.2 + Sites 9.1 environment - which is working quite fine.
Now I want to also fetch the metadata of the keyword for a custom navigation model.
What is the recommended way to  get a keyword metadata (or it is not even recommended to use intelligent navigation with keyword meta).

also, in NavigationLinks - a typical keyword id is recorded as `t<tcm id of category>-k<tcm id of keyword>` - I really do not want to do string manipulation here.

Any input is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean with “Intelligent Navigation”, exactly? Dynamic Navigation? The On-demand Nagivation API? https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-1EDA5776-1F5F-4C2F-8058-BAF1084C5CC4

Comment: thats correct @RickPannekoek. edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are just referring to the Dynamic Navigation capability in DXA: I vaguely remember that there was an issue in the CIL Taxonomy API that custom Keyword metadata was not returned and therefore this wasn’t exposed in DXA’s `TaxonomyNode` models.

We are talking years ago when we were working on the implementation of Dynamic Navigation in DXA 1.6 (on top of SDL Web 8.1). Much has changed in the meantime, but it may be that this limitation was never removed.

Indeed, the ID of a Taxonomy Node is a combination of Taxonomy/Category ID and Keyword ID; you need both to identify a Taxonomy node in the CD Taxonomy API.

Comment: Thanks @Rick for the confirmation; this helps - yes I tried debugging the DXA providers code and can't see it coming.

Comment: Just wondering if there is a thought other than manipulating the string id of the keyword and writing a custom controller or customer provider for it.

Comment: DXA nowadays obtains the Taxonomy from the GraphQL Content Service (with DXA Model Extension). I'm not sure if the Keyword custom metadata is in that response (I have a suspicion it's not), but if it is you could directly interface with the GraphQL client.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm it is not there, and you may need to fetch the keyword meta

Comment: @PankajGaur, did you find any solution to this? How can we retrieve Keyword Metadata information? Can we use GraphQL to get the Metadata information for the Keyword?

Comment: I did, through fetching full meta of each key word and keeping them in a cache